# How to use Kinesis with Log4J Baigaizeva

Tags: log4j, amazon-kinesis

I would like to use Amazon Kinesis with Log4J. Does anyone have any sample code that I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has published a Log4J appender for Amazon Kinesis. You can find the details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/kinesis-pig-publisher.html).